# Bluemix - Machine Learning - Authorization header has not been provided

Tags: curl, machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, bearer-token

I am trying to deploy an online model and following the instructions I first get the token

```
curl --basic --user username:password https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v3/identity/token
```

Which works fine, but then when I try to get the instance details with this command:

```
curl -X GET --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer  $token" https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v3/wml_instances/{instance_id}
```

I got this error:

```
{
  "code": "missing_authorization_header",
  "message": "Authorization header has not been provided.",
  "target": {
    "type": "header",
    "name": "Authorization"
  }
}
```

I already tried all different syntax I know plus the ones I found google searching but none help, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check that you parsed the response from the `identify/token` call and only added the token to the `Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token part` ?

Comment: You are right, I was getting the wrong part of token, thanks